# How To Completely Fill A CSS Grid Box With An HTML Element?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

-- Edits Below --

I’m hoping to ask for your help on how to fill a CSS Grid box with an html element.

Once we create a CSS Grid and assign an html element to a location between some rows and columns, if we want the element to take up the full space between these rows and columns, do we need to change the element dimensions directly? Or is there another way?

For example, if we have an img element and assign it to a CSS Grid location, we can set the width and height properties of the img to 100% and the img will fill between those grid rows and columns. I’m hoping to ask if there’s another way to fill that space with the img without changing the img element’s dimensions directly? Or, at least without using the height and width properties?

-- Edits --

Thank you so much for taking the time to let me know ! I've included a minimally reproducible example below of HTML and CSS.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="grid-container">
    <div id="stretch-text">Stretch</div>
    <div id="unstretched-text">Unstretched</div>
    <img id="stretch-img" src="example.jpg">  
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
#grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 300px 300px;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 300px;
}

#stretch-text {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 2;
}

#unstretched-text {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
}

#stretch-img {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    /* width: 100%;
    height: 100%; */
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and consider updating your post with a [mre] of your code. As it's written, your question is very broad and we're here to troubleshoot specific code issues and we can't troubleshoot your code if we can't see it! :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try using `place-items: stretch;` ?

Comment: Thank you both so much! I've added a minimally reproducible example. If either of you would still have the time to take a look, I would really appreciate it. Again, thank you so much !

Comment: Also, Simp4Code, I just want to let you know I tried place-items: stretch but it did not seem to have the effect of stretching the element across the css grid